# Find running job priority

Tags: hadoop, jobs

How can I find the priority used by a job running in Hadoop?

I tried to use Hadoop commands like `hadoop job`, `yarn container`, or `mapred job`, etc., but couldn't find how to get the running job priority.

Comment: Try using command from this.https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#job. You might get something.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I noticed before. this command seem to set priority, but no get priority method.

Comment: Have you tried `hadoop job -list` command?.It will give you entire information with priority of the running hadoop job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getJobPriority()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.11/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobStatus.html#getJobPriority()) method in your mapreduce code.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
hadoop job -list
```

...it will show you the information of all running jobs with priority.

```
hadoop job -list all
```

...will show you the information of all the job(Running,Success,Fail) with priority.